# Implement Kerberos authentication using C# on IIS

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos, ntlm

I have configured the kerberos settings in IIS, still it fallback to NTLM authentication.

Can you tell me the proper troubleshooting method for kerberos.

Can you explain detail (Configuration and code implementation) about the kerberos implementation in c#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos is wide to troubleshot, if it fails to NTLM you'll have to brainstorm your configuration.

To test you can start by analysing the request/response header with a browser plugin (I use Httpfox for firefox), or by using the ASP.NET Authentication test page which might help you further http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2013/01/08/asp-net-authentication-test-page.aspx

Keep in mind that kerberos might fail if:

- try to login from the actual IIS server computer
- using an IP address instead of a name
- no SPN registered
- duplicate SPNs registered
- SPN registered against wrong account (KRB_ERR_AP_MODIFIED)
- no client DNS / DC connectivity
- client proxy setting / Local Intranet Zone not used for target site
  Also check your configuration for updates

About your next question:

> Can you explain detail (Configuration and code implementation) about the kerberos implementation in c#.

It is even wider, I could not go shorter than the excellent article we find here: "Authentication in web services using C# and Kerberos (POC)" http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27554/Authentication-in-web-services-using-C-and-Kerbero

Please update when you get more details about your error.

Comment: Hi Damien, I have did as per your instructions, but i have received the below error message as 0*19 KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED. Let me know if there is any configuration missing.

Comment: If i have removed the pre authentication for the particular AD user account, again it fall back to NTLM, but this time nothing error log can be found in system log.

Comment: Hi @damien please let me know once checked.

Comment: Preauth issues... I suggest you enable the event logs on the server:

Enabling Kerberos Event Logging on a Specific Computer

    Start Registry Editor.
    Add the following registry value:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters

    Registry Value:
    LogLevel

    Value Type:
    REG_DWORD

    Value Data:
    0x1


    If the
    Parameters
    subkey does not exist, create it.

Comment: also try with a different client, check firewall and disable antivirus

Comment: Do i need to set the firewall setting as i have attached below?


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQNG.png

Comment: Hi @Damien, Actually i have did the kerberos logging and found the error message as "KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED". But as per the below MS trouble shooting document we can skip this error                                     ` This error often occurs in UNIX interoperability scenarios. MIT-Kerberos clients do not request pre-authentication when they send a KRB_AS_REQ message. If pre-authentication is required (the default), Windows systems will send this error. `